# MySQL: Выборка из двух таблиц (отношение один ко многим)

Tags: mysql, join

Имеется две таблицы: с авторами книг и с самими книгами. Нужно выбрать 10 авторов с возрастом больше 30, но меньше 40 лет, со всеми их книгами. 
Родил вот такой запрос :

```
SELECT 
    author.name, 
    books.title 
FROM 
    `author` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `books` 
On 
    books.author_id = author.id 
WHERE 
    author.age > 30 AND 
    author.age < 40 
GROUP BY 
    author.name 
LIMIT 10;
```

(либо здесь http://pastebin.com/XdhZRVz3)

Но проблема в том, что так выводит только одну книгу каждого автора, а надо все. 
Помогите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
   SELECT a.name, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(b.title) books 
     FROM authors a 
LEFT JOIN books b ON b.author_id = a.id 
    WHERE a.age BETWEEN 30 AND 40 
 GROUP BY a.name 
    LIMIT 10;
```

Вложенный запрос:

```
   SELECT a.name,
          b.title
     FROM authors a
LEFT JOIN books b ON b.author_id = a.id
    WHERE a.id IN (SELECT id
                     FROM authors
                    WHERE age BETWEEN 30 AND 40
                    LIMIT 10);
```

Второй вариант вложенного запроса:

```
   SELECT a.name,
          b.title
     FROM (SELECT id,
                  name
             FROM authors
            WHERE age BETWEEN 30 AND 40
            LIMIT 10) a
LEFT JOIN books b ON b.author_id = a.id;
```

Кстати, отношение между авторами и книгами - многие-ко-многим. Потому как одну книгу могут писать в соавторстве несколько человек (Стругацкие, к примеру).

Comment: Согласен, но в даном случае задание стоит так, что это один ко многим.

Comment: Спасибо большое, решение помогло :)

Answer (score 0):

подзапрос надо

```
    SELECT 
    author.name, 
    book.title 
FROM 
(select * from `author` limit 10) `author`    
LEFT JOIN 
    `books` 
On 
    books.author_id = author.id 
WHERE 
    author.age > 30 AND 
    author.age < 40 
;
```

Comment: Условия по возрасту внутрь подзапроса нужно перенести.